Discrepancy between total impact and forecast differences in Dynamic Factor Model
The total impact of a month generated by the dynamic factor model is different from the difference between the predicted value of that month and the predicted value of the previous month.
According to the code in the statespace_large_dynamic_factor_models tutorial: statespace_large_dynamic_factor_models.
First, let's look at the changes in the forecast for the second quarter of 2020:
2020-02 forecast for real GDP growth in 2020Q2: 2.68%
2020-03 forecast for real GDP growth in 2020Q2: 2.52% # (decrease 0.16 pct)
2020-04 forecast for real GDP growth in 2020Q2: -8.23% # (decrease 10.75 pct)
2020-05 forecast for real GDP growth in 2020Q2: -37.17% # (decrease 28.94 pct)
2020-06 forecast for real GDP growth in 2020Q2: -22.33% # (increase 14.84 pct)

Second, let's look at the Total impact on 2020Q2 forecast:
# Print the table of impacts from data in each group,
# along with a row with the "Total" impact
(group_impacts.T
.append(group_impacts.sum(axis=1).rename('Total impact on 2020Q2 forecast'))
.round(2).iloc[:, 1:])




group
2020-03
2020-04
2020-05
2020-06




Total impact on 2020Q2 forecast
-0.16
-10.70
-29.30
17.18



We can see that the total impact on 2020Q2 forecast for 2020-03 is equal to the forecast value of actual GDP for 2020-03 minus the forecast value of actual GDP for 2020-02, but there are different degrees of difference in other months.
What is the reason for this difference? Normally, should the total impact of a certain month on the 2020Q2 forecast be equal to the difference between the forecast value of this month and the forecast value of the previous month?
References:
https://github.com/ChadFulton/tsa-notebooks/blob/master/statespace_large_dynamic_factor_models.ipynb
